# How can I program RFduinos and how can I connect them with Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, communication, ide

My RFduino dev kit just arrived, and for my project I have to connect a few RFduinos via Bluetooth and light up certain LEDs attached to the RFduinos. If anyone could point me in the right direction as to where I can program them/how I can connect them, it would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am starting on a similar project (without the Dev Kit).  Hooking the Bluetooth module to the RFduino is pretty straight forward, PWR to PWR, GND to GND, remember to cross the transmission wires: TX to RX & RX to TX.

In your `void setup()`, you need to start the connection:

```
Serial.begin(9600); // check your documentation to see the baud rate
```

In your `void loop()`, read or write to/from the bluetooth connection with serial write/read. `Serial.read()` or `Serial.write()`

Remember that Bluetooth is a communication protocol, not a controller.  You don't mention WHAT you are connecting your RFduinos to using Bluetooth. You still need a controller capable of sending a signal to light up the LEDs using Bluetooth.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. I plan to use my iPhone as a controller, but I also want to make my own App. I don't want to use the pre-existing RFduino LED controller app. (the one on the app store)

Comment: Sweet!  I'm doing the same thing with Android!  However, life has put this project on hold for a while.  Please keep me posted on your progress.